# How to change CSS class after Ajax request in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I can't figure out what I'm supposed to use in the following situation:

- The template list a bunch of photos
- Each photo element has a ng-click
  event that marks the photo as selected and sends an Ajax request to
  save the photo
- When the save happens, I want to update the class of
  the photo element to show it as selected

I have a call tie to my ng-class that works when the page loads, but it is called too early when the user clicks. It should be called after the save.

How do I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could modify the ng-class variable when the ajax is completed

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example. I just tried something but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like:

```
<a ng-click="uploadImage('id')">
 <i ng-class="{'image-not-uploaded': !sendImage, 'image-uploaded': sendImage}"></i>
</a>
```

**In JS**

```
...
$scope.sendImage= false; 

 ajax_post.uploadFile_init($scope.uploadedFile)
    .then(function (result) {
        if(result.status == 200){
            $scope.sendImage= true;
        }                 
    }, 
    function (error) {
        alert(error.message);               
    });
```

Here, you change class according to `$scope.sendImage` state.

I used some `factory` for upload file but you can change it to Image.

```
angular.module('FeederLiteApp', []).factory('ajax_post', ['$http',  function(_http) {   
return{              
    uploadFile_init: function(uploadedFile){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("uploadedFile", uploadedFile);
        var upload_promise =  _http.post("src/php/data.ajax.php",
            fd,
            {
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':undefined
                },
                transformRequest:angular.identity
            });

        return upload_promise;
    }       
  }   
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try something around that.

Comment: For some reason my ng-class call doesn't output anything and remains as a HTML attribute
`code`
    <div ng-repeat="photo in currentAlbumPhotos" class="ng-scope">
        <div ng-click="selectPhoto(photo)" ng-class="{'selected': photoSelected[photo.id]}">
          <img src="https://photos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/943297_159960067506837_358851884_s.jpg" width="180">
        </div>
    </div>
`code`